# VisualGDB y proyecto c++

Tags: c++, stm32

Estoy desarrollando desde VisualGDB para STM32 y el proyecto que se ha creado, un cmake, se ha generado automáticamente en C, querría que visualstudio me compilase y me reconociese C++.
¿Cómo puedo configurar VisualGDB para que el proyecto este en C++ y no en C  ?.

Comment: Si no nos das más información es difícil ayudarte. Visual Studio también funciona con C.

Comment: Claro, el problema que tengo es de portabilidad. He iniciado un proyecto nuevo para STM32 con visualstuidio+Visualgdb+STM32CubeMx y a este proyecto quiero añadirle funciones que he desarrollado anteriormente en Workbench 8.0 en C++ para este mismo microprocesador. El problema es que por defecto, al crear un proyecto nuevo en VisualGDB con CubeMX lo crea en C y no reconoce librerías como string.h por ejemplo.

Comment: perdón, no es que no reconozca string.h, es que no reconoce cosas como printf, std::string temporal="";   temporal.c_str();  , int a = temporal.find("paloma"); ... etc.

Comment: Cmake debería poder solucionar esos problemas por ti